# Making lightweight web browser - Gecko vs Webkit vs ???; Qt4 vs Qt5 vs?

Tags: qt, memory, browser

Since I'm not fully content with any of the mainstream browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera), and none of the less popular ones I've tried out (nearly a dozen), I decided to DIY and make a web browser I would like the best.

The main goal is to make it use as little RAM as possible - my laptop has 1GB installed and is not extendable. But it must preserve all the basic functionality I need - full JavaScript support, support for external Flash plugin (as in, the Adobe's one), and maybe ad blocker using EasyList filters.

But I don't have much experience in making native GUI apps, and after quite some time spent googling I've found virtually none info about what frameworks would do the job best. So I'm asking:

1. Which of these: Gecko or Webkit, uses less memory in general case? If they are about the same, which is easier to use and "mess in" (as in, remove redundant functionality)? Are there any other browser engines I could give a try in this task?
2. Which one uses less memory for displaying basic controls: Qt4 or Qt5? What about QtWebkit - did it grow fat in Qt5, or just the opposite? If I decided to use Qt4, would I be able to update the Webkit engine (from QtWebkit) to new versions? How hard is integrating vanilla Webkit or Gecko into Qt application?
3. Do you know any other native GUI libraries that would do the job as good or better than Qt, especially in the matter of memory consumption? wxWidgets? GTK+? I need to support both Windows and Linux, at least.
4. Which of the open source JS engines uses the least amount of memory? It doesn't necessarily need to run fastest.

Comment: If creating a browser of your own is going to be a hobby or you just want to study stuff, then it is totally fine. My point was that creating a new working browser, is a _large_ project. Have you considered making your own plugins to Firefox or Chrome that change the features you hate in them? That would be a much smaller project and you would get some experience how those browsers work. Of course, with plugins you cannot change how much memory the browsers use, but if you build your browser from ready made libaries, you don't have very much control of their memory usage either.

Answer (score 2):

Gecko is often considered to consume less memory than WebKit, but this depends a lot on how the browser is implemented. However, it's really (almost unbelievably) easy to create (at least a simple) web browser with Qt which also has a JavaScript engine. Qt 4 is more stable and consumes less memory than Qt 5 (this was the case some months ago, I don't know if things have changed). The choice is yours.

Comment: I wasn't asking about any JS engine. I was asking specifically for low-memory JS engine. Because I could duct tape any engine to my browser if I had to - the question is, which one I should.

Comment: I don't know which option is the best, but they say that at least V8 is quite fast and requires somewhat little memory.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain if your open to rethinking how you want to do this, but you may find Netsurf, http://www.netsurf-browser.org/about/ and especially the projects page, http://www.netsurf-browser.org/projects/ to be useful for this project.  I think this would require you to move away from the standard frameworks, and it will most likely be much more work, but I believe this will allow you to reduce your footprint substantially.

As for the GUI?  "The overall idea of [libNSFB] is to provide a generic abstraction to a linear section of memory which corresponds to a visible array of pixel elements on a display device."  Sounds like fun.

Also, +1 for "Also, what's wrong with you? [...]".  Stick it to the man.  Firefox in particular has started becoming less intuitive, and addons only paint over the rot.

Answer (score 2):

I have made some quick tests on my old PC with 1.5GHz CPU and 384MB RAM with Lubuntu 12.04.

I have installed Chromium 33 (Blink), Firefox 28 (Gecko), Epiphany 3.4.1 (WebKitGTK) and QupZilla 1.6.5 (QtWebKit4). First, I opened a single tab - Google, then I opened 5 tabs - CNN, Yahoo, YouTube, Google, Facebook, and I measured the memory used by browsers using Task Manager. Then I run the HTML5 Test and V8 Benchmark. Results:

```
          1 tab  5 tabs  HTML5  V8
Epiphany  68MB   155MB   351    988
QupZilla  86MB   204MB   304    881
Firefox   101MB  188MB   424    353
Chromium  151MB  281MB   495    963
```

Verdict: the most memory efficient is Epiphany/WebKitGTK and the most bloated is Chromium/Blink.

Apart from (Qt)WebKit(GTK), Gecko and Blink, have you tried [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com)?

Comment: Meaningless data.  The rendering engine is using an unknown portion of the memory reported.

Answer (score -5):

Firefox its the best for long. Support  webm, ogv, mp4. The way to show  and many html tags its atless much better than webkit. This is my opinion.

Comment: Your answer is wrong in so many places. First, it's completely irrelevant to my problem - we're not talking about browsers, but browser engines. Second, it's completely irrelevant to my problem - we're not talking about cool features, but memory consumption. Third, your grammar is not only making my eyes bleed, but makes your whole post barely understandable. What was that part with HTML tags about? Fourth, ending post with "this is my opinion" is enough for me to dismiss it on the spot as lacking credibility.